# Block access to files by URL

Tags: apache

I am new to webhosting and building a very small PHP website as a part of my project. It will not be used for practical purposes for now, but still I want to make sure that it is not TOO insecure.

I have a few files which I don't want users to access by URL(some text and CSV files) but my PHP code should be able to use them. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Can you place them outside the web root? That would be the best thing to do

Comment: Okay I placed it out of my web root and gave gave the user group in which www-data user (which apache uses) is present the privileges to access that file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want them accessed by the web server but just by PHP, *the best thing is to just keep them outside the webroot*.

You can block access using .htaccess, but that will prevent you from using pretty much any other web server than Apache, and it adds un-necessary overhead (and a possible vulnerability if the .htaccess is accidentally removed or configured wrong)